# How do I set Drupal's $base_path variable?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I can't find where this is set, but apparently it is because it is tacking on an unnecessary dir to the base_url after I migrated from dev to live. I just want to set it to '/'

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 6 it's definitely in the settings.php file in your sites directory ( most likely drupal/sites/default/settings.php ).

I strongly assume that its the same for D7.

Comment: $base_url is in settings. $base_path is not.

Comment: As far as I know $base_path is the base_url.